# adding new resolution problem

Tags: display-resolution, xrandr

```
amal@amal-H81M-S:~$ sudo xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  41
  Current serial number in output stream:  41
```

Comment: I used the exactly same line for my monitor and it worked. Looks like your monitor neds different parameters. Regretfully, I can't remember how I got them ("from somewhere on the net" :-( ) It worked for 16.* and 18.04 versions of ubuntu.

Comment: no i tried different parameters but it not worked